# Different in notions of measure, norm, length,

Tags: normed-spaces

What are the differences in notion of Measure(Lebesgue measure), Norm(may be Euclidean), or even length or diatance?
If Norm can be used to ascertain size or length or distance why do we need the concepts of MEASURE.
I want to know about different fields(or spaces) where one can work but not the other.
Do these ideas agree in any space?

Comment: Norm generalizes lengths of vectors. Measure generalizes higher dimensional sizes, like area, volume.

Comment: In the real line the concept of length is available for a simple set like an interval. Measure is a generalization of length and you can assign measure to set of rationals, set of irrationals etc.